# Initial payment processor setup for PayPal

Tags: payment-processor, paypal, configuration

I am trying to build a form for membership. How can I initially configure PayPal for payment processing?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/contributions/payment-processors/ for setup on Payment Processors, including PayPal. You can setup the Payment Processor and then create a Contribution Page for membership.